# IPTables log connection pid on OUTPUT chain

Tags: linux, iptables, socket

I'm trying to find `pid` of a socket using iptables OUTPUT chain  log, or even better adding it into the log.

My current iptable rule:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix='[PID]' --log-level 7 --log-uid
```

I'm a bit frustrated since I know that iptables' `owner` module can filter items by `pid` (using `-m owner --owner-pid` flag) which means that the info is there, but I can't log it.

I know that it impossible to do with INPUT chain since iptables is a kernel process, but for OUTPUT chain it should be possible.

any idea? or even of how to cross some log data in order to get PID of OUTPUT chain connections?